# Making TextView inside Gridview completely round

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview

I am trying to make a custom `CalendarView` in Android to which I could add events. I am trying to make something similar to the original `CalendarView`, but I struggle getting the `TextView` inside of the `GridView` to be completely circular, that is even on the click animation to have a circular border.

I've made a custom `TextView` called `CircularTextView` with which I tried to override the `draw` method in order to get the full circular effect. But the problem is the background on click is still square.

The `CircularTextView` class:

```java
package com.example.owncalendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class CircularTextView extends TextView {

    public CircularTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        int h = this.getHeight();
        int w = this.getWidth();

        int diameter = ((h > w) ? h : w);
        int radius = diameter / 2;

        this.setHeight(diameter);
        this.setWidth(diameter);

        canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, radius, circlePaint);
        Log.d("DRAWN", "Drawn");
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The view loaded inside the GridView:

```java
<com.example.owncalendar.CircularTextView android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_textview"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

The `round_textview` drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"/>

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

It should be something like this:
[image: Example]

Comment: You need to create selector drawable for that.

Comment: I will try that and come back with an answer. Thank you